# jQuery remove() html 5 audio mediaelementjs

Tags: jquery, html, firefox, audio

Hi I have a simple problem and I hope there is a simple solution.

I have an HTML audio element on my page

```
<audio id='foo' control="control">
    <source id='mp3' src='somefile.mp3' type='audio/mp3'>
</audio>
```

In jQuery I have `$('audio').remove();` but the audio player stays on the page. I have also tried `$('#foo').remove();`.

I'm using the mediaelementjs player, I don't know if that is what is causing the problem.

Anyone know how I can remove audio elements?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could wrap it in a placeholder div and then do `$("#wrapper").html("");`

Comment: Brilliant, a very elegant solution!

Answer (score 0):

I got this issue while removing the `src` attribute before removing the element from the DOM.

Removing the `src` attribute for autoloaded `<audio`> elements (`<audio "preload"="auto" ...`) aborts the connection on some devices (like `firefox-os`). Instead of removing the `src` attribute, simply clear it:

```
    try {
      $el.attr("src", "");
    } catch(error) {}

    $el.remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution (not a workaround)
Wrap into an element and do so:

HTML

```
<div id="element">
    <audio id='foo' control="control">
        <source id='mp3' src='somefile.mp3' type='audio/mp3'>
    </audio>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$('#element').empty();
```